# Adjust volume with Android Terminal Emulator command?

Tags: android-emulator, volume-control

My volume up/down buttons do not work, and it's also a European phone that cannot change the volume until you agree to the high volume message. The thing is that from options this message does not appear you have to use the physical buttons, agree and then the volume will go up. Im playing around and I was wondering if I can use a command on the Terminal emulator to adjust the volume up and down?

Phone is rooted, thanks.

Comment: What phone do you have?

Comment: @ABochur It's an old Xiaomi Redmi 3

Comment: When you say that you have to agree to the message when changing volume, is this for any level or it's it just when going too high? `from options this message does not appear` so when you go into settings/notifications and sounds, and try putting the volume to the highest, what happens? And BTW do you have earphones plugged in during this time?

Comment: [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27391326) and also the linked one in comments (possible duplicate)

Comment: @ABochur The message appears from 60% upwards for once. When I try to change it from the settings, it just goes back to 60%, without high volume message popping up. Yes, earphones are plugged, and the volume always goes to 50% automatically when plugging them in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following commands to change the volume from Android Terminal emulator (or other terminal emulator apps):

Volume Up:

```
input keyevent 24
```

Volume Down:

```
input keyevent 25
```

In case pressing the volume key once shows the current volume, you can input the command twice to increase/decrease the volume

```
input keyevent 25; input keyevent 25
```

Toggle Mute/Unmute

```
input keyevent 164
```